# Simplifying rational expresions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is a equation to simplify. It looks simple, but I'm confused:

$$ \frac{28b^6}{7b} $$

I can obviously simplify and get:

$$ 4b^5 $$

The only problem I'm facing is that, in the given expression, there is the value 7b in denominator. Do I have to include a domain?:
$$b\neq0 $$

Comment: Yes.$\,\!\,\!\,\!$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're solving an equation with this expression in it,  you need to remember that $b$ cannot be zero.  That is,  $0$ isn't a solution.